# Array difference work when not in variables

Tags: ruby, arrays

if given the following

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]

a&b #=> [3]
b - a&b #=> [4,5]
b - a #=> [4,5]
```

why does this work

```
[1,2,3] - [3] #=> [1,2]
```

but not this

```
a - a&b #=> [] ??
```

Comment: Nice Goggly! I liked it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `-` has higher precedence here than `&`:

```
a - (a&b)
# => [1, 2]
```

Comment: whaaaaaa, shouldn't this comply with math precendece?

Comment: @NickGinanto: In math, mixing arithmetic operators with boolean operators makes no sense. If it were to comply with "math precedence", it would most likely be a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

```
2.1.2 :006 > a - a&b
 => []
2.1.2 :007 > a - (a&b)
 => [1, 2]
```

You can get ruby operator precedence table from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table).