# Difference between "not" and "!" in ruby

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic

Are `not` and `!` synonyms, or are they evaluated differently?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table

Answer (score 200, accepted):

They are almost synonymous, but not quite. The difference is that `!` has a higher precedence than `not`, much like `&&` and `||` are of higher precedence than `and` and `or`.

`!` has the highest precedence of all operators, and `not` one of the lowest, you can find [the full table at the Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

As an example, consider:

```
!true && false
=> false

not true && false
=> true
```

In the first example, `!` has the *highest* precedence, so you're effectively saying `false && false`.
In the second example, `not` has a lower precedence than `true && false`, so this "switched" the `false` from `true && false` to `true`.

The general guideline seems to be that you should stick to `!`, unless you have a specific reason to use `not`. `!` in Ruby behaves the same as most other languages, and is "less surprising" than `not`.

Comment: I have used 'not' in the past to make negated conditionals easier to read. Meaning if the entirety of the conditional should be negated I felt comfortable using 'not' rather than '!'. I like it when my code reads like inglush

Comment: @jaydel Could you use `unless` in that case?

Comment: @Jacob, yes, definitely. `unless` is just not really favored in the ruby world. The general consensus is that it just gets in the way when `!` works just as well in most situations. I'm sure there are cases where unless may be more expressive, but I steer clear.

Comment: I disagree that `unless` is disfavored. [The closest thing we have to a consensus](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#unless-for-negatives) says otherwise.

Comment: Just wanted to share an example of how surprising `not` can be. In Python, I sometimes assign booleans to variables to make if-statements easier to read. That might mean using the pattern `x = not y`, where y is something complex. In Ruby, `x = !y` works, but `x = not y` gets `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '('`. The precedence order means this needs parentheses around the right of the assignment op to work: `x = (not y)`.

Answer (score 20):

An easy way to understand the `not` operator is by looking at `not true && false` as being equivalent to `!(true && false)`

Answer (score 2):

I have an **RSpec-driven example** here: [Ruby's not keyword is not not but ! (not)](https://richstone.io/rubys-not-keyword-is-not-not-but-not/)

In essence:

- They differ in precedence
- They are not aliases
- `!` can be overriden, whereas `not` cannot be overriden
- when you override `!` then `not` will be overriden too, hence it must be using `!` under the hood