# Why does the block of this if statement seem to be executed before the conditional in ruby?

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

I'm currently working on [a codegolf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69965/exploding-cats), and so I'm trying to use as few characters as possible.

This code:

```
#example data
x=[1,2,3]
a=5.times.map{5.times.map{' '}}
#problematic code:
a[b][c]=x.pop if a[b=rand(5)][c=rand(5)] == ' '
```

returns a (quite strange) error:

```
test.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  b
```

Which boils down to "Can't find `b`, did you mean `b`?". (to which the answer is yes).

This only happens with a **2D array** with an **inline if** statement.

This code also runs fine:

```
if a[b=rand(5)][c=rand(5)] == ' '
  a[b][c]=x.pop
end
```

It seems like it should be exactly the same, but it behaves differently. Why is this?

I thought it might have something to do with precedence, but I had a look at [the ruby precedence table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060235/1267729) and everything would seem to be what I expect, so I'm not sure.

Comment: So `a[b][c]=x.pop if ...` does not run fine, but `a[b]=x.pop if ...` does?

Comment: @sawa yes, but I've removed the latter since I realized that of course array != `' '`, so the block of the if wasn't executing. My bad.

Comment: @ndn see my comment, it's because in my 1d array example, the conditional evaluates to `false` so the block is never executed. If you add `|| true` the same error happens. It is a duplicate.

Comment: @shelvacu, yea, my bad. Saw it afterwards