# `and` is the same as `&&` but why does `and` have lower precedence?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, `and` is the same as `&&`, but why does `and` have lower precedence?

```
false and false || true # => false
false && false || true # => true
```

Comment: Well, it's not "the same" precisely because of the lower precedence. What is your question, again?

Comment: Your code has a hidden problem, can you see it?

Comment: Anyway, you can check Ruby operators precedence here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely correct that the humanised operators have lower precedence. There is an excellent (and brief!) article on this [here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) if you want more information.

Simplest answer (from that article):

> Properly understood, `and` and `or` are control flow operators, not boolean operators.