# Will `&&` always run before `if` on the same line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Will every `&&` run before `if` on the same line in Ruby?

For example:

```
@building.approved = params[:approved] if xyz && abc && mno...
```

Can an unlimited number of `&&` be used on the right side of an `if` without using parentheses?

I'm inclined to use parentheses but I'd like to understand the default behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby operator precedence table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table)

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the nominated exemplar: Knowing operator precedence won't help the OP, since `if` is not an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything after the `if` must be part of the condition by virtue of the syntax. The only way to get around this is to be really specific:

```
(@building.approved = params[:approved] if xyz) && abc && ...
```

Which is obviously not what you're intending here.

Operator binding strength isn't an issue here since `if` is a syntax element not an operator, so it has the absolute lowest priority.

The only conditions that will be evaluated are the ones that produce a *logically false* value, or come after one that was *logically true* as the first one to return *logically false* will halt the chain.

That is:

```
if a && b && c
```

Will stop at `a` if that is a logically-false value. `b` and `c` will not be evaluated. There's no intrinsic limit on chaining though.

Comment: What do you think of adding 'something about short-circuiting and the `&&` operator?  It's relevant to the question.

Comment: @wayneconrad Ah, due to the peculiar wording of the question I've added a note.

Comment: Yes, that's the wording that made me think it relevant.  I'll delete this comment, and the other one, shortly.

Comment: Leave it up. I think it helps show the train of thought here.