# Ruby && and = operators misudnerstanding

Tags: ruby, operators, operator-precedence

What do you think would be the result of the next expression in Ruby?

```
    a = 10 && b = 25
```

Try to calculate in the ming and only then use `irb`. So, if we take a look at the Ruby documentation about [Operators Precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) then we will se that `&&` operator has a higher priority than `=`. So you must think that Ruby will evaluate the expression in the next way:

```
    a = ((10 && b) = 25)
```

But Ruby does a job in another way:

```
    a = (10 && (b = 25))
    # => 25
```

So, the priority of the `=` in `b = 25` is higher, then `&&`. Can anybody explain why it is happend like so?

Comment: "One must think ruby will do this: `((10 && b) = 25)`" - nope. This does not make any sense. Left hand side of `=` is not an assignable entity here.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the way Ruby identifies **bareword identifiers**

When it comes across an identifier like `a`, it has to resolve it by checking to see if it is a **keyword, local variable** or **method** in that order.

- `keyword` - if `a` is a keyword then use it as a keyword
- `local variable` -  is there an equal sign to the right of `a`, then it must be a local variable. If not check if there is any local variable `a` defined. These points are very important, it is the reason why you can't call **writer methods** in instance methods without explicitly calling `self`.

Take for example this code

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name #creates both attr_reader name & attr_writer name=(text)

  def print_name
    name # => attr_reader method name is called and returns nil

    name = 'Bola'#even though we have the name= method, it doesn't get called
    #what happens is a local variable name is created instead
    #this is as a result of how ruby interpreted the bareword identifier name
    #not a keyword but has an equal sign so must be a local variable

    name # this time local variable is used instead of method because it is resolved first
  end
end
```

- `method` if it's not resolved as a keyword or local variable then it assumes it's a method and tries to call it.

So this is how the code is evaluated

- what is to the left of `&&` 10, which it can make sense of
- compare that `10` to what is on the right of `&&` which is `b` but it has to evaluate what `b` is so it resolves it using the procedure I described above which results in local variable `b = 25`. Assignment operations always return the values on their right which is `25`
- compare `10` and `25` which returns `25`
- finally a = `25`

With that being said `&&` does have higher priority and the `=` signs are of the same precedence. Hope this explanation was clear.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks. Question: When you say _"compare `10` and `25`"_ are you not just _checking if both are  true_, in which case the latter is always returned in Ruby, rather than it being a comparison?

Comment: Its checking if the values are `truthy`. In Ruby the only values that are not truthy are `false` and `nil`. Simply put any value apart from `false` and `nil` in comparison expressions are interpreted as `true`. The _latter_ is not necessarily returned, If it had been `false && 25` OR `25 && false`, `false` would have been returned . I'm glad this was able to help. :)

Comment: @sagarpandya82: What's returned is "last evaluated value". Which is different from "last value in the list" (because of short-circuiting)