# Why does double shovel in Ruby not mutate state?

Tags: ruby, string

I ran into this weird side effect that caused a bug or confusion.  So imagine that this isn't a trivial example but an example of a *gotcha* perhaps.

```
name = "Zorg"

def say_hello(name)
  greeting = "Hi there, " << name << "?"
  puts greeting
end

say_hello(name)
puts name

# Hi there, Zorg?
# Zorg
```

This doesn't mutate name.  Name is still `Zorg`.

But now look at a very subtle difference. in this next example:

```
name = "Zorg"

def say_hello(name)
  greeting = name << "?"
  puts "Hi there, #{greeting}"
end

say_hello(name)
puts name

# Hi there, Zorg?
# Zorg?  <-- name has mutated
```

Now name is `Zorg?`.  Crazy.  Very subtle difference in the `greeting =` assignment.  Ruby is doing something internally with the parsing (?) or message passing chaining?  I thought this would just chain the shovels like `name.<<("?")` along but I guess this isn't happening.

This is why I avoid the shovel operator when trying to do concatenation.  I generally try to avoid mutating state when I can but Ruby (currently) isn't optimized for this (yet).  Maybe Ruby 3 will change things.  Sorry for scope-creep / side discussion about the future of Ruby.

I think this is particularly weird since the example with less side effects (first one) has two shovel operators where the example with more side effects has fewer shovel operators.

**Update**
You are correct DigitalRoss, I'm making it too complicated.
Reduced example:

```
one = "1"
two = "2"
three = "3"
message = one << two << three
```

Now what do you think everything is set to? (no peeking!)
If I had to guess I'd say:

```
one is 123
two is 23
three is 3
message is 123
```

But I'd be wrong about two.  Two is 2.

Comment: Just a note, the canonical way to join strings in Ruby is interpolation, rather than concatenation with plus or double shovel. That avoids the mutation question altogether. I am guessing that Matz chose to make the double shovel associate the way it does to support the use case of "a" << b << "c". Otherwise people coming from languages like C++ would have been quite surprised to see the side effects.
Re avoiding mutating state, Ruby supports functional style as well as many other styles; Ruby isn't a pure functional language and I think that's intentional.

Comment: Totally.  I usually do "#{one} #{two} #{three}".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we convert your `a << b << c` construct to a more method-ish form and throw in a bunch of implicit parentheses the behavior should be clearer. Rewriting:

```
greeting = "Hi there, " << name << "?"
```

yields:

```
greeting = ("Hi there, ".<<(name)).<<("?")
```

[`String#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) is modifying things but `name` never appears as the target/LHS of `<<`, the `"Hi there ," << name` string does but `name` doesn't. If you replace the first string literal with a variable:

```
hi_there = 'Hi there, '
greeting = hi_there << name << '?'
puts hi_there
```

you'll see that `<<` changed `hi_there`; in your `"Hi there, "` case, this change was hidden because you were modifying something (a string literal) that you couldn't look at afterwards.

Comment: Yep.  Nice.  `one = "1"; two="2"; three="3"; greeting = (one.<<(two.<<(three)))` does what I expect.

Answer (score 3):

You are making it too complicated.

The operator returns the left-hand side and so in the first case it's just reading `name` (because `"Hi there, " << name` is evaluated first) but in the second example it is writing it.

Now, many Ruby operators *are* right-associative, but `<<` is not one of them. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060235/140740

Comment: Thanks for the left-/right-associative terminology that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side of your `=` is evaluated left to right.

When you are doing

```
"Hello" << name << "?"
```

The operation starts with `"Hello"`, adds `name` to it, then adds `"?"` to the mutated `"Hello"`.

When you do

```
name << "?"
```

The operation starts with `name`, and adds `"?"` to it, mutating name (which exists outside the internal scope of the method.

So in your example of `one << two << three`, you are mutating only `one`.