# Can I change the associativty of an operator?

Tags: ruby, associativity

There is a very nice table of Ruby's operators and their respective associativities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table). According to this table, a fair number of operators are left associative, and this is not particularly useful for me. Is there a way that I can change a left associative operator to be right associative? The way my code is set up `x * x * x` will not work, but `x * (x * x)` will work. This is because my specific implementation of `x * x` has it returning an array. Because of this an array can be the parameter passed to the method but it cannot be the object calling the method. I cannot override the `*` method in the array class because there is elsewhere in my project where its default functionality is being used and therefore monkey patching is not an option. Is there a way to change the associativity of the `*` operator for my class?

Comment: I suspect that the associativity is handled by Ruby's parser and so `x * x * x` will always be interpreted as `x.*(x.*(x))` no matter how your class is defined. Can you use a method other than `.*`? Could you have `x * x` (or `x.some_method(x)`) return something other than an array? At the very least a subclass of `Array` so that you could leave the default behavior alone?

Comment: @Max What I actually have is `def method_missing(method, *args); [self, method.to_sym, *args].flatten; end` in my class. I guess my best bet would be to create an array subclass to handle this. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

No.

Like almost all languages, Ruby does not allow you to change the associativity of operators. (Some exceptions are Ioke, Seph, Haskell, Fortress, and maybe Perl6.)

For instances of class [`Numeric`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html), there is a [type coercion protocol](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-coerce) which could be abused to give the appearance of changing the associativity of arithmetic operators, but that's a really brittle hack and not what the protocol is intended for.