# Ruby two strings in an IF condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails project I've `if` statement with string conditions which doesn't work.

```
  if shop.details['company_role'] == 'CEO' || 'founder'
        'Other'
      else
        shop.details['customer_kind']
      end
  end
```

When I've case with `company_role = founder` it didn't return me 'Other' but `customer_kind`

Comment: You better look at the warning you should receive

`
2.6.2 :002 > a = 'test'
 => "test"
2.6.2 :003 > if a == 'one' || 'two'
2.6.2 :004?>   puts 'Other'
2.6.2 :005?>   else
2.6.2 :006?>   puts 'Else'
2.6.2 :007?>   end
(irb):7: warning: string literal in condition
Other
 => nil
2.6.2 :008 > if a == 'one' || false
2.6.2 :009?>   puts 'Other'
2.6.2 :010?>   else
2.6.2 :011?>   puts 'Else one'
2.6.2 :012?>   end
Else one
 => nil
`

Comment: And than to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table ruby precedence table(`==` runs first, than you take if false || 'founder')

Comment: @YuriyVerbytskyi pasting irb sessions in comments rarely works.

Comment: @Stefan oh yeah, but it doesn't looks like anybody but PO will be interested in that as an answer(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premise is a little off.  The `if` statement *works*, but it's not producing the results that you expect.  It's basically doing the equivalent of this:

shop.details['company_role'] == 'CEO' # is this true? then stop
  | "founder"                           # is this true?  yes, it's *always* truthy

The solutions provided will all work.  Your choice mostly depends on your code style.  I'd go with the second option because I personally like the test with an emphasis on the tested data.

Two further suggestions.  First, the test itself could be extracted to a method.  This would improve readability of your code.

```
def shop_type
  if executive?
    'Other'
  else
    shop.details['customer_kind']
  end
  # alternate: executive? ? 'Other' : shop.details['customer_kind']
end

def executive?
  shop.details['company_role'].in?('CEO','founder')
end
```

Lastly, it strikes me that the decision about whether or not a `Shop` includes an "executive?" seems to be useful information in a number of contexts.  As such, it looks like the `executive?` method would be better placed inside the `Shop` model so that knowledge of the internal organization of the `Shop` does not leak all over your system.

```
shop.executive? ? 'Other' : shop.details['customer_kind']

class Shop
  ...
  def executive?
    shop.details['company_role'].in?('CEO','founder')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
if ['CEO','founder'].include?(shop.details['company_role'])
  'Other'
else
  shop.details['customer_kind']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%w(CEO founder).include?(shop.details['company_role']) ? 'Other' : shop.details['customer_kind']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if shop.details['company_role'].in?('CEO','founder')
  'Other'
else
  shop.details['customer_kind']
end
```

Comment: I've just tried this in Ruby 2.2.2 and the method isn't defined, it may belong to later versions of Ruby, or to a library.

Comment: @AJFaraday [`Object#in?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F) – this is a Rails question

Comment: Ahh, I missed that detail. No problem.

Comment: Remove your other answer or combine the 2 answers (and fix the errors in your other answer)