# How to hide a specific user if it's the one being login in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to hide the record item info of use on my table if its the use that is login at the moment. Basically I tried to use `<% if !current_user.id === user.id %>` then he needs to show it.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Id</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
           <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      <% @users.each do |user| %>
<% if !current_user.id === user.id %>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><%= user.id %></th> 
          <td><%= user.name %></td>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete user?"}, class: "btn btn-primary btn-user" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

But this one did not work. How can I hide the information of the user item if he is the one being login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use unless and using ==

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% unless current_user.id == user.id %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= user.id %></th> 
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete user?"}, class: "btn btn-primary btn-user" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
<% if !current_user.id === user.id %> # Here is an error. You are comparing false with integer, also using `===`
```

Try this one

```rb
<% if !(current_user.id == user.id) %>
```

or short version: unless

```rb
<% unless current_user.id == user.id %>
```

[Check this one for understanding why error happened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060235/4453714)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Devise or an equivalent implementation you can write an `unless` clause like the following:

```rb
    <% unless user == current_user %>
        ...other content...
    <% end %>
```

It works without the ids.

Note that this will fail if the page is accessible for non-logged users (as there is no *current_user* to compare), so you might need to replace the clause for this one:

```rb
    <% unless user_signed_in? && user == current_user %>
        ...other content...
    <% end %>
```