# Confusion accessing array values vs array position

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say we have the following code:

```
def run(input)
  start = 0
  lap = 0

  while true
    opcode = input[start]
    input1 = input[start + 1]
    input2 = input[start + 2]
    output = input[start + 3]

    if opcode == 1
      input[output] = input[input1] + input[input2]
    elsif opcode == 2
      input[output] = input[input1] * input[input2]
    elsif opcode == 99
      puts "breaking"
      break
    else
      puts "CANT RECOGNIZE THAT OPCODE"
    end
    start += 4
    lap += 1
  end
  puts input
  puts "finished after #{lap} loops"
end

input = [1,9,10,3,2,3,11,0,99,30,40,50]
run(input)
```

I understand why printing `input1` I get the number stored in that possition in the array (9), but I don't get why printing `input[input1]` (`input[input[start + 1]]`) accesses the value the number in that position (9) points to (30).

The code works for the exercise but I don't understand why.

Comment: Tip: Learn about `case` which can help make your code a lot easier to follow as well as more efficient.

Comment: Also consider looping with `input.each_slice(4) do |opcode, input1, input2, output|` to break out in chunks of 4.

Comment: Thanks. I actually saved your response from yesterday, but I got it working in a primitive way like this and was thinking of refactoring it later. I still don't understand this though.

Comment: Almost everything in Ruby is an expression that resolves to some value. `input[9] == 30`, so anything that *resolves* to an index of `9` will also return `30`, because that's the value stored in the input array as the ninth element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call `Array#[]` you're doing a look-up, and if you nest these then you get an index-based "pointer" to another value. This is common in some data structures as it can store one copy of a value that's used in multiple places, among other things. One example in common use is DNS, as per [RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).

In your example it's easier to understand when you consider the [*order of operations*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table). Ruby, like many languages, evaluates from the inside out, or in other words:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

a[a[1]]
# => 3
```

Where that's evaluated as if it were expressed as:

```
x = a[1]
# => 2
a[x]
# => 3
```

There's no limit on the number of times you can nest an index resolution like this *provided none of the indexes exceed the array bounds*, as `a[1234]` returns `nil`, and `a[nil]` is an error. You can theoretically do this indefinitely, though in practice you'd rarely do it more than a handful of times.