# Can operator precedence be changed in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

In Ruby, the operator precedence is (implicitly) defined, and documented in a couple of places, for example at [Ruby operator precedence table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060234/ruby-operator-precedence-table).

Some languages allow setting or changing the operator precedence, for example in Prolog: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=op/3.

Is that possible in Ruby too?

For example switching the order of addition and multiplication:

```ruby
1 + 2 * 3 + 4
# => standard precedence results in 1 + 6 + 4 => 11

1 + 2 * 3 + 4
# => changed precedence would result in 3 * 7 => 21
```

Comment: It's not possible, the operator precedence is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question regarding the [AoC's problem of today](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/18), but I found this old issue:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7336

So I guess it's not feasible.

Comment: Ha, you guessed the reason for the question correctly :-D I found a hackish solution though... https://twitter.com/jschulenklopper/status/1339886541737512960?s=20

Comment: Nice find; that suggestion in the Ruby language issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

OK, changing operator precedence in Ruby is explicitly stated as not possible. I found a naughty solution though that I'll share for fun, using hack-ishly overloading two operators that have similar or higher precedence than another one.

```ruby
class Integer
  def %(operand)
    # `%` has same precedence as `*`.
    self + operand
  end
  def **(operand)
    # `**` has higher precedence than `*`.
    self + operand
  end
end

puts eval("1 + 2 * 3 + 4")
# => 11

puts eval("1 % 2 * 3 % 4")
# => 13

puts eval("1 ** 2 * 3 ** 4")  
# => 21
```

Don't do this in production code...

Comment: Here's my celebratory tweet: https://twitter.com/jschulenklopper/status/1339886541737512960?s=20