# how to send rails parameters with square brackets route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the equivalent to `new_product_path(:param_key => 'param_value')` with the square brackets routes like `[:new, :products, :param_key => 'param_value']`? This doesn't work. How do I send parameters with the square brackets?

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets [represent an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565/what-do-the-different-brackets-in-ruby-mean) (as in most other languages) - which means if you're looking to pass params "in square brackets", it will need to be an array of values

---

**Params**

You have to remember the Rails `params` object is [really just a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885990/rails-params-explained) which is set when you submit your HTML form data. This means if you're trying to read certain params, the way to access them is through the hash: `params{ your: "attributes", here: ["1", "2", "3"]}`

This means if you're trying to set / access params "in square brackets", you'll need to create an array of values, like this:

```
<%= form_for @var do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
<% end %>

params { tags: ["1", "2", "3"]}
```